# Displaying the validation error messages in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a table in which the rows are getting replicated using ng-repeat. Each row have a  text for a value and a  which shows the error message. So these will also be replicated. The error message will be shown on validating the input.

```html
<tr ng-repeat="validationRule in form.validationRules">
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="delimiter" 
           ng-pattern="/^(?:([^A-Za-z0-9_\s])(?!.*?\1))+$/" 
           maxlength="1" title="Enter the delimiter!" 
           ng-model="validationRule.delimiter" 
           style="width: 20px;" required />
    <span ng-show="appForm.delimiter.$dirty && appForm.delimiter.$invalid"> 
       <span style="color: red" 
             ng-show="appForm.delimiter.$error.required"
      class="help-block">Field is required!
       </span>
       <span style="color: red" 
             ng-show="appForm.delimiter.$error.pattern" 
             class="help-block">Enter valid delimiter!
       </span>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Now, let's say, at a point of time, I have 5 rows. When the validation on delimiter fails, the error message is displayed on all 5 rows rather than the current row in which the validation fails.

The approach I tried was to:

1. add a function in js which will try to figure out the current row.

```js
$scope.isCurrentRow = function(index) {
  var currentRow = $scope.form.validationRules.index(this);
  alert("currentRow: " + currentRow);
  if (index == currentRow) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

2. add the function call in the ng-show condition

```html
<span style="color: red" 
      ng-show="appForm.delimiter.$error.pattern && isCurrentRow($index)"
      class="help-block">Enter valid delimiter!
</span>
```

This approach is not at all working. 
Is there a better approach in angular way that I could try?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this. It should work

```
<tr ng-repeat="validationRule in form.validationRules">
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="delimiter[$index]" 
           ng-pattern="/^(?:([^A-Za-z0-9_\s])(?!.*?\1))+$/" 
           maxlength="1" title="Enter the delimiter!" 
           ng-model="validationRule.delimiter" 
           style="width: 20px;" required />
    <span ng-show="appForm.delimiter[$index].$dirty && appForm.delimiter[$index].$invalid"> 
       <span style="color: red" 
             ng-show="appForm.delimiter.$error.required"
         class="help-block">Field is required!
       </span>
       <span style="color: red" 
             ng-show="appForm.delimiter[$index].$error.pattern" 
             class="help-block">Enter valid delimiter!
       </span>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: No its not working. I even tried delimiter[{{$index}}], but that also not working.

Comment: Put delimiter[{{$index}}] at both spans

Comment: No, that also didn't work. I have mentioned in my previous comment. I will try some other way.